# Where do you put facebook share appID in MVC?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I have a custom share button for facebook and functions for it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.1';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and

```
<script>document.getElementById('piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn').onclick = function () {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        display: 'popup',
        href: window.fbSheareUrl,
    }, function (response) { });
}</script>
```

so I get an error when try to share : Invalid App ID: The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID.
I cant fin place to put it if you can help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App ID is required for the Share Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#params

You can either submit it as parameter, or add it in the implementation of the JS SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart#loading

You need to create an App for that: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/